# Dealing with Error "found in NAME formula"

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

I have tons of ".xls" format excel files that haves #NAME error in it.

I need to open each one, collect data from a specific range. but when I try to open it with xlrd I get the following error: "ERROR *** Token 0x2d (AreaN) found in NAME formula"

Code is below:

```
import xlrd


book = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Users\metin.unlu\Desktop\Python\renk_study\labs\2-19.xls",ignore_workbook_corruption=True)
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
```

While the error is safe explatornary and I know the cause of it, I have no idea how to solve it without openning each excel file manually and fixing it.

Comment: This problem is not inherent in having a "#NAME" error. If I create a .xls with a name error (by setting the value of a cell to `=x()` for example) and save it, I can then open it with `xlrd` and even access the cell with the error (although it returns an erorcode 'error:29', but that makes sense). Please describe in greater detail how you can recreate the problem from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In more details, I take the data from an outdated data collection program in our company. To collect the data, we use save as excel option. The saved files have this inherit problem that causes the "#NAME" error. I get the same error when I manually open it in excel but excel automatically corrects it to #REF! error so the file opens. For that I assumed maybe the files are corrupted but ignore corruption does not help as well. I am sorry I have no info to debug other than this information.

Comment: If it's hard to reproduce the problem in a smaller setting, it will be hard to provide you with an answer. All I was saying is that creating a sheet that has just any `#NAME` error does not reproduce your problem. So, unless you can provide some information on how one might go about creating a sheet that has this problem, or perhaps provide a link to such a file if someone wants to try themselves, there's no way to help unless someone happens to know what's commonly going on in a case like yours.

Comment: Thank you Grismar, you are right. I will try to find a work around.